# Jquery date time picker issue

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker

Can anyone please help me with the date time picker and explain why it is not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6FGgA/

```
$(function () {
   $('input').datetimepicker(
    {
     addSliderAccess: true,
     sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
 });
```

Comment: But i want to use a jquery date and time picker. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of datetimepicker you need to use datepicker:

```
$(function () {
    $('input').datepicker(
    {
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/6FGgA/66/

EDIT: In case I misunderstood and you meant to use **datetimepicker** defined in the included library there, it seems that the site you've referenced doesn't allow cross-site requests for the scripts. I copied the contents of those scripts into the fiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/6FGgA/69/) and you can now use your original code.

Answer (score 0):

What is your need.datepicker or datetimepicker

**if you want datepicker try this:**

```
$(function () {
   $('input').datepicker(
    {
     addSliderAccess: true,
     sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
 });
```

**if you want datetimepicker check this link:**

```
http://runnable.com/UgCgGBRfEwILAAEt/how-to-create-date-time-picker-using-jquery-ui
```